# Scroll FlatList to top when tapped on the status bar

Tags: react-native

Is there a chance to implement scrolling to the top of a flatlist (or the whole screen) on tap on the status bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ios only prop:

**onScrollToTop** :
Fires when the scroll view scrolls to top after the status bar has been tapped.

**scrollsToTop** :
When true, the scroll view scrolls to top when the status bar is tapped. The default value is true.

**Link** :
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscrolltotop

Comment: Thank you. That's nice but I'd like the same but for flatlist. There's no possibility to use ScrollVeiw instead.

Comment: FlatList inherits ScrollView props. So, this should work in flatlist aswell.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist